# IndexError: tuple index out of range -- String formatting

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I'm making a little imageboard kind of thing, and I'm trying to do a MySQL insert, but this piece of code is throwing an error:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO posts(date,replies,title,link,text,userip,username) VALUES('{}',{},'{}','{}','{}','{}','{}');".format((self.date.isoformat(),self.replies,self.title,self.embed,self.text,self.userip,self.username)))
```

And here's the error (running this on top of Falcon/WSGI):

```
2015-05-05 17:37:14,135 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-05 17:37:14,136 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
2015-05-05 17:37:14,136 :    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
2015-05-05 17:37:14,136 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in exception
2015-05-05 17:37:14,136 :    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
2015-05-05 17:37:14,136 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error
2015-05-05 17:37:14,136 :    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2015-05-05 17:37:14,136 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in _log
2015-05-05 17:37:14,137 :    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
2015-05-05 17:37:14,137 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1244, in makeRecord
2015-05-05 17:37:14,137 :    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
2015-05-05 17:37:14,137 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 284, in __init__
2015-05-05 17:37:14,137 :    self.threadName = threading.current_thread().name
2015-05-05 17:37:14,137 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in currentThread
2015-05-05 17:37:14,137 :    return _active[_get_ident()]
2015-05-05 17:37:14,137 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
2015-05-05 17:37:14,138 :    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
2015-05-05 17:37:14,138 :  File "/home/isitcoldinfallschurch/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 175, in __call__
2015-05-05 17:37:14,138 :    responder(req, resp, **params)
2015-05-05 17:37:14,138 :  File "./new.py", line 89, in on_post
2015-05-05 17:37:14,139 :    thispost.insertdb()
2015-05-05 17:37:14,139 :  File "./new.py", line 57, in insertdb
2015-05-05 17:37:14,140 :    curs.execute("INSERT INTO posts(date,replies,title,link,text,userip,username) VALUES('{}',{},'{}','{}','{}','{}','{}');".format((self.date.isoformat(),self.replies,self.title,self.embed,self.text,self.userip,self.username)))
2015-05-05 17:37:14,140 :IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Your second set of` `{ }`
 are missing single quotes `VALUES('{}',{},'{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')`

Comment: Why are you creating another tuple? Simply do `format(self.date.isoformat(),self.replies,self.title,self.embed,self.text,self.userip,self.username)`

Comment: @Cyber If the value is actually a number, then you don't need them I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra brackets in your `.format` input which is doing this (treating the inputs as a single tuple).

Proof of concept:

```
>>> "{}{}".format((1,2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> "{}{}".format(1,2)
'12'
```

---

So instead of this

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO posts(date,replies,title,link,text,userip,username) VALUES('{}',{},'{}','{}','{}','{}','{}');".format((self.date.isoformat(),self.replies,self.title,self.embed,self.text,self.userip,self.username)))
```

do this

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO posts(date,replies,title,link,text,userip,username) VALUES('{}',{},'{}','{}','{}','{}','{}');".format(self.date.isoformat(),self.replies,self.title,self.embed,self.text,self.userip,self.username))
```

As @chepner notes in the comments below, a better way to do this would be to use the below, where the `%s` are filled by the cursor using the tuple passed as the second argument to execute:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO posts(date,replies,title,link,text,userip,username) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", (self.date.isoformat(), self.replies, self.title, self.embed, self.text, self.userip, self.username))
```

Comment: I don't know what type `curs` is, but I strongly suspect the OP should not be using `format` at all to generate the SQL statement.

Comment: Something like `curs.execute("INSERT INTO posts(date,replies,title,link,text,userip,username) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", (self.date.isoformat(), self.replies, self.title, self.embed, self.text, self.userip, self.username))`

Comment: @chepner You are right, the type can not be accurately inferred, though I think it is a cursor; curs can be short for cursor and it has the `.execute` method as well.

Comment: Yup! it's an SQL cursor from MySQLdb. That being said, I don't see the huge difference between using .format() and % in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution mu! Looks like it works, creds to thefourtheye as well for catching that too.

Comment: Because with `format`, a value with a single quote will change the parsing of the statement passed to MySQL. Use the cursor to provide properly quoted parameters; don't try to generate the SQL string dynamically.

Comment: Notice I'm not using the Python `%` string operator; the `%s` are filled by the cursor using the tuple passed as a second argument to `execute`.

Comment: Ohhh I see, ok, thanks chepner! Did not know you could do that with execute.

Comment: Be sure to check your documentation; I don't know if the same placeholders are used by all DBAPI implementations, but there should be something similar.